# Active directory authentication restriction to specific domain [ASP.NET]

Tags: asp.net, azure, authentication, active-directory, adal

I created an `ASP.NET` web application with Active Directory authentication. 
It works fine when I put my email *me@domain.com*, it will redirect me to the correct Federation service. But I want to redirect automatically and prevent other Microsoft users from logging in. What should I add to this sign in method and please redirect me to the correct documentation if any.

```
 public void SignIn()
    {
        // Send an OpenID Connect sign-in request.
        if (!Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.Challenge(new AuthenticationProperties { RedirectUri = "/",  }, OpenIdConnectAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you have configured your app to be single-tenant, only the users and guests in your directory can use your application or api. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-and-multi-tenant-apps

Comment: Did my comment answer your question?